# Apache Camel FTP File Name Non English Character Encoding Problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am working on a ftp route that gets a file from one endpoint and moves to another. If file has non english characters like ö,ç,ğ etc. filename in the header wont be correct. But when saved to endpoint filename seems to fine. I believe this is because program and windows 10 uses different encodings. But I have no idea to how to fix it.

- For example; the original file name is aslan *çilek.txt* becomes
  *aslan Ã§ilek* when the file enters the processor.

***EDIT

```
                    from(...)
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws 
                                Exception {
                                String fileName =exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME).toString();
                                String newFn = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf('.')) + "_"
                                        + sdf.format(new Date()) + fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf('.'));
                                exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelFileName", newFn);
                            }
                        })
                        .doTry()
                        .to(...)
                        .bean(x.class, "successfulLog(*,${file:name})")
                        .doCatch(Exception.class)
                        .bean(x.class, "failedLog(*,${file:name},${exception.message})");
```

convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8") is added after the special character problem. With or without I still have the same problem.

Comment: As long as your charset is UTF-8, you won't face any issues. How are you checking the file name header inside the processor (debug mode on your IDE ?)

Comment: I use a processor for accessing Exchange.FILE_NAME header. I will update my question